# How to insert value in cell when match found in CSV

Tags: regex, powershell, csv, filestream

I'm looking to add two columns at the beginning of an existing CSV that will be used to store any matches found on that line and the line number. I have the search working correctly to find matches, I'm just not sure how to insert/append the found values to the existing (or newly created) spreadsheet.

My first issue is when I go to add the 2 new columns named "ICHit" and "Line" it deletes my entire CSV. I'm also not sure where to start with appending the values on the lines that match in the CSV.

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

## Data Structure

```
COLUMNS = ICHit,Line,UserName,EmailAddress,Code

CellValues = MATCHGOESHERE,LINENUMBERHERE,Bob,Bob@gmail.com,12345


$date = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d"
$OutPutFileName = "SearchResults" + $date + ".csv"
$CSV= "U:\Found\$OutPutFileName"
$RXSearchList = "12345,bob@gmail.com"
$filetosearch = "\\server\SpreadsheetToSearch.csv"


Import-Csv $filetosearch |  #add new columns
Select-Object *,@{Name='column0';Expression={'setvalue'}} | 
Export-Csv $filetosearch -NoTypeInformation


$File2 = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($CSV,$true) #Append or Create a new file Stream. 
$File2.WriteLine('ICHit,Line') # New Columns to add

$file = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader ($filetosearch)  # Input Stream
    while (($text = $file.ReadLine()) -ne $null ){
        foreach ($RX in $Global:RXSearchList){
            foreach ($match in ([regex]$RX).Matches($text)) {
                    
                    $Global:File2.WriteLine("{0},{1}",$match.value,$text)  
            }
         }
        }
            $file.close();  
            $Global:File2.close() #file2
```

Comment: NB: Your code is reading from and writing to the same file in the same pipeline, with nothing to force all lines to be read before the first one's written; so I  suspect you'll hit issues working with multi-line csvs.

Comment: For the cells, read a line, run a single match on it, append it to a new file. The regex must match each line, so it has to be something like `((?:[^,]*,){3}([^,]*).*)` which gets the 4th column or whatever, where the replacement is `Group2, LINENUMBER, Group1` and where LINENUMBER is a counter incremented in the loop. The regex is the tricky part, the rest is just mundane code loop stuff. So it depends on if you want to alter the original line in any other way (like shifting columns). But it is doable with a series of captures.

Comment: Thank you. My goal is to add the two new columns. Whenever I find a match, I populate values in those two new column's cell values on the line that matched.

Comment: I was able to add two new columns at the end. Now I just need to figure out if I have the line number, can I append the matched values in those new columns.   I used                               
             Import-CSV $filetosearch |
ForEach-Object {

  $data1 = 'ICHit'
  $data2 = 'Line'

  $_ | 
  Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ICHit -Value $null -PassThru |
  Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Line -value $null -PassThru

} |
Export-CSV $OutputFile

Comment: Yeah, you should only get 1 match per line, so you don't need a foreach() for the match. If it matched, then write out the line, then read the next line. Also, you need a counter for the line number and something like `$Global:File2.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}",$match.value,$line_num,$text) ` . Also, it looks like you have a list of RX you're running on each line.